# Selenium: How to enter white space as the value of a text field?

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I have a form text field that is being populated with a default value. I would like to clear the value and enter white space to assert that the expected validation occurs. I am using Selenium RC and the PHPUnit Selenium extension. How can I achieve this?

Note: I have already tried doing these, but they do not work:

```
$this->type('FirstName', "  "); //spaces
$this->type('FirstName', "\t"); //tab character
```

They clear the value from the field, but they do not enter the white space into the field.

**Update:** I found that [if you are using Selenium IDE, you can type white space by using their `${space}` variable](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#whitespace) but this does not work when using Selenium RC and the PHPUnit Selenium extension.

Answer (score 2):

recently I am having the same problem just like Andrew where the ${space} isn't work in Selenium RC. I found out that Zugwalt's solution is useful. Here is what I did to capture the whitespace.

```
selenium.focus("txt_textbox1");
selenium.keyPressNative("32");
strOutput = selenium.getEval("this.browserbot.findElement('txt_textbox1').value = ' ';");
```

Hope this help ;)

THanks @!

Comment: .keyPressNative("32"); using this puts the space in and then if you want to remove it you can also do .keyPressNative("8");. My purpose of this was to refresh a jquery datatable with a filter in the text box and it worked great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this in the phpunit-selenium code on github and made a pull request to the maintainer.

Here is my gist if anyone cares:

https://github.com/undernewmanagement/phpunit-selenium/commit/1b783ba8cfe4736f525b316a75a991e0a701afd1

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript injection and manipulate the value directly

```
selenium.getEval("this.browserbot.findElement('FirstName').value = ' ';");
```

Note this will not fire off any events so you would have to manually trigger them if desired.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting it's value to an empty string ('')?

Comment: What would be the syntax to set an element's value?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the keyPress() function to "press" the spacebar?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `selenium.typeKeys('FirstName'," ");`
Please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for phpunit with Selenium:

```php
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $textField = $this->byCssSelector('.blah');

        // ...

        $textField->clear();
        $textField->value(" ");

        // test assertion to follow
    }
}
```

If you want to enter a sentence, the following won't work:

```php
$textField->value("this is a sentence.");
```

The following will:

```php
$textField->value("this");
$textField->value(" ");
$textField->value("is");
$textField->value(" ");
$textField->value("a");
$textField->value(" ");
$textField->value("sentence.");
```